# Add event when an element is moved (jQueryui sortable)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have several divs that I can order by dragging and dropping them (exactly as shown on the example in http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).
I would like to add an event each time one of this div is dropped, any idea how could I achieve so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop)

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    cancel: ".fixed",
    stop: function( event, ui ){
        alert('change');
    }
});
```

Here is a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/1355/)